# Create TagHelpers in Class Library for ASP.NET Core 3

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

How can you create `TagHelper`-classes in a **separate class-library** with the changes to ASP.NET Core 3?

In ASP.NET Core 1.x and 2.x, you could reference just the NuGet-package `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor` to allow your classes to derive from `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.TagHelpers.TagHelper`.

In ASP.NET Core 3.x, there seems to be only one big package named `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App`, which **cannot be found on NuGet**.

The solution should support using the contained `TagHelper`-classes in **both ASP.NET Core 3 and earlier versions**.

Comment: Target `netcoreapp3.0` and add a _`FrameworkReference`_ for `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App`.

Comment: @KirkLarkin: This is probably the correct answer. Could you create a real answer to this? Maybe with an explanation for this change and what any side-effect could be.

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at [Migrate from ASP.NET Core 2.2 to 3.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio).

It explains that projects that only reference `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor` (such as your class library) need to add a reference to `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App`.  However, this is automatically included for projects that target `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web` (an MVC app or WebAPI, for example).

Quote from the [FrameworkReference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio#framework-reference) section (second bullet applies to your project):

> Features of ASP.NET Core that were available through one of the
>   packages listed above are available as part of the
>   `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` shared framework. The shared framework is the
>   set of assemblies (.dll files) that are installed on the machine and
>   includes a runtime component, and a targeting pack. For more
>   information, see The shared framework.
>
> - Projects that target the `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web` SDK **implicitly**
>     reference the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` framework. No additional references are required for these projects:
>
>   ```
>   <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
>     <PropertyGroup>
>       <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>
>     </PropertyGroup>
>     ...
>   </Project>
>   ```
> - Projects that target `Microsoft.NET.Sdk` or `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor` SDK, should add an **explicit** `FrameworkReference` to `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App`:
>
>   ```
>   <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor">
>     <PropertyGroup>
>       <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>
>     </PropertyGroup>
>
>     <ItemGroup>
>       <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
>     </ItemGroup>
>     ...
>   </Project>
>   ```

Comment: I made my library-project use `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">` but now I get errors about not having a `static Main` method - so what's the solution to that without adding a fake startup class?